# How to take date in Text field

Tags: java, swing, date, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

I am new to Java and I'm having trouble getting the date format for a `Textfield`. I'd like to take the date input by the user and input it into a database. I've tried using `JCalender` but it's not working because I failed to configure the palette. Are there any other options other than `JCalender`? Thanks in advance.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Delivery Date Action

              tf3.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      char c = e.getKeyChar();
      if (!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9') ||
         (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
         (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_SLASH)))        
      {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Valid");
        e.consume();
      }
    }
  });


        tf3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
               int i = Integer.parseInt(tf3.getText());


            }
```

Comment: you want to date in date field text box with data format

Comment: Perhaps instead of using a JTextField (and limiting the user to a specific syntax), it'd be easier to use three JComboBox's (Month, Days, Year) as the input option.

Comment: Don't use key listeners, they interfere with the document updates and you have no idea in the event chain where the are getting called.  Better to use a [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html).  You could also take a look at [SwingX `JXDatePicker`](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t45447.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JFormattedTextField is a subclass of JTextField.

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
JFormattedTextField txtDate = new JFormattedTextField(df);
```

you can add validation event on it

```
txtDate .addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      char c = e.getKeyChar();
      if (!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9') ||
         (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
         (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_SLASH)))        
      {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Valid");
        e.consume();
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: You can also validate that its correct date format by using regex.

Comment: There is no need to use a `KeyListener` in combination with a text component in Swing. Use `DocumentFilter`s or `DocumentListener`s instead

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for a JFormattedTextField?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html

Answer (score 2):

Use JFormattedTextField with data format

See

http://www.kodejava.org/examples/234.html

and

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/JFormattedTextFieldwithSimpleDateFormat.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can put three different Drop Down Boxes to specify Day, Month and Year. You need not to check for other validations. If 31 date is possible for that month, Leap year check and Order Date < Delivery Date.

Comment: Only last mentioned three validations + any your application specific validation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Mohammod Hossain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13927765/2821954), I have written this simple class. I hope it can help.

```
public class JDateTextField extends JFormattedTextField{

private final String format;
private final char datesep;
private Component pare = null;

/**
 * Establece el componente padre para los mensajes de dialogo.
 * <p>
 * @param pare
 */
public void setPare(Component pare) {
    this.pare = pare;
}

public JDateTextField(final String format) {
    super(new SimpleDateFormat(format));
    this.format = format;
    setColumns(format.length());
    //if(format.contains("-")) datesep=KeyEvent.VK_MINUS;
    //else
    if (format.contains("/")) {
        datesep = KeyEvent.VK_SLASH;
    } else {
        datesep = KeyEvent.VK_MINUS;
    }

    addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            try {
                Date date = getDate();
            } catch(ParseException ex) {
                showError("Por favor introduzca una fecha válida.");
            }
        }
    });
    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            String s = "" + c;
            if (s.matches("|[a-z]|i")){
                showError("Carácter no válido detectado " + s);
                e.consume();
            } else if(!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')
                    ||(c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
                    ||(c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)
                    ||(c == datesep)||(c == KeyEvent.VK_COLON))){
                showError("Carácter no válido detectado " + c);
                e.consume();
            }
            /*
             * else{
             * try{
             * Date date=getDate();
             * }catch(ParseException ex){
             * showError("Por favor introduzca una fecha válida.");
             * }
             * }
             */
        }
    });
    setValue(new Date());
}

private void showError(String error) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pare, error + "\n\tEl patrón válido es: " + format, "Fecha NO válida", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}

public Date getDate() throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat frt = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    return frt.parse(getText());
}
```

}